# Out of Memory using .Refresh BackGroudQuery:=False

Tags: excel, vba, memory

I have this same code which consumes 3x more memory in one file vs another file. The initial memory usage for both files is just under 500MB. But when I hit this spot in the code the memory usage spikes up to 3000MB in one file and 9800MB in the other. The later causing out of memory issues for some of my coworkers.

On the "GetAccess" sheet there is a table where data is dumped from a database table. The memory spikes when I hit the .Refresh BackGroudQuery:=False

I use the same table on "GetAccess" to pull data from different tables in the database by changing the sql command CT = "  this part changes   "

Before this section I am cleaning out existing data before updating the data from database

```
    CT = Array("SELECT * FROM ProdData2")

Sheets("GetAccess").Visible = True
Sheets("GetAccess").Select
 Cells(1, 1).Select
 'Division = Sheets("TeamTypes").Range("Q1").Value
 
    With Selection.ListObject.QueryTable
        
        .CommandText = CT
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False   ' MEMORY spikes here
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

After this I start pulling from GetAccess to another sheet

Comment: You can't be more selective in your query?

Comment: I need to pull all of the rows.  Limiting the columns would potentially help.  how ever the amount of data in my query is small.  325 rows x 90 cols.  I have another file in which the Memory is not impacted.

Comment: Hard to see how that little data is reaching 3GB   Seems like there's some other problem here.

Comment: I agree.  I tried just pulling 2 columns (ID and DateTime) and the data size blew up.  When I tried to pull just ID there was no issue.  I will see if pulling other columns other than DateTime will have the same impact or not.